# Connecting to AWS EC2 with MySQL Workbench over Standard TCP/IP

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, tcp

Hi I'm trying to connect to my AWS EC2 Instance using MySQL Workbench. I want to do this with a standard TCP/IP Connection. Is this possible? When I open the port on AWS I still can't connect but I can through SSH.

Comment: SSH uses a standard TCP/IP connection.

Comment: Sorry to rephrase, how do I do it without the need for a .pem file?

Comment: so, you want to make your mysql database accessible to the world?